# No network adapters in Virtual Machine after converting from VirtualBox to Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2012, virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I've migrated from Oracle's Virtual Boxx to Microsoft Hyper-V running in Windows 2012R2. My virtual machines are also all Server 2012 R2. After migrating from VirtualBox to Hyper-V and creating new Virtual Switch in Hyper-V and assigning virtual machines to those virtual switches, I cannot get any of my virtual servers to connect. The network adapters screen is also empty. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Give us more details please.  Is your first Hyper-V VM?  How is your virtual switch configured?  Do you have networking working in any Hyper-V guests on that system?  Which type of network adapter did you assign to your guest VM?  Does your network require VLAN trunking...

Comment: Do the VMs have Network Interfaces configured in Hyper-V? Because I'm thinking they don't.

Comment: The virtual switch it's configured as an external switch with in it's own adapter. Not sharing with the host OS. The network does not require vlan trunking. It's a simple single subnet lan.

Comment: The virtual switch it's configured to use the second NIC in the server. The host OS is using adapter 1.